# React component render pauses and resumes when saving the source file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, vite

I just recently switched from `create-react-app` to `vite` and I am experiencing a weird bug. It is almost as if re-rendering stops and resumes when I press CTRL+S in vscode.

I have a component that fetches a config in `componentDidMount` such as.

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
  await this.props.getEnvironment();
  if (this.props.environment.webSocketUrl === '') {
    logger.error('[Key] Could not get environment');
  } else {
    doSmth()
  }
}
```

`this.props.getEnvironment()` is in `generalRestActions` and uses `dispatch` to set `environment` into the store.

The environment is then fetched such as

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  environment: state.general.environment,
});
```

This worked perfectly before - when environment was set, a Material UI switch got into the "ON" position.

**The bug I am experiencing is, that when I reload the page the switch is in the "OFF" position and it seems as if the re-rendering of the component PAUSED although it should re-render since store value changed. As soon as I press CTRL+S in visual studio code the re-rendering resumes and the switch goes into the "ON" position.**

Also, if I print the store value in render() BEFORE pressing CTRL+S the correct value is shown but the switch is in the "OFF" position. If I press CTRL+S then, the component reflects the changed value in the store by setting the switch to "ON".

I have tried everything and I cannot figure it out.

Any ideas why rendering pauses? Why isn't `componentDidMount` being called again when props change?

EDIT: the only thing that fixes this is adding `componentDidUpdate` but it shouldn't be needed since the component is using `connect`.

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component));
```

**EDIT 2: I noticed this happens in other components as well. When I `await` a REST call, which saves the fetched data into the store and then get it from the store as `this.props.data`, the fetched value is undefined. It only works if I use `componentDidUpdate`.**

Comment: Could it be that webpack's HMR work differently?  Maybe Vite's HMR doesn't unmount to then mount, and simply updates.

Comment: I tried completely deactivating HMR and it didn't change a thing.